# how to trace the view from df command in case of new mount point

Tags: linux, bash, disk-usage

My target is to verify consistently if some new mount point was added, and I need to verify this by df command

So the following command actually view the df , and in case of new mounting point then we can see the change

```
 watchdf
```

but I ask if we can trace the df info by bash script that will print “new mount point was added” , in case that new mount point appears in the df 
is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Watching the output of `df` is a bad idea as its output cannot be processed reliably and it doesn't include all mounted filesystems (unless you use the `-a` option with the GNU or busybox implementation).

On Linux (`util-linux` 2.20 and above), you can use `findmnt -p` to poll for changes on mount points.

That commands works by doing a `poll(events=POLLPRI)` on a file descriptor open read-only on `/proc/self/mountinfo` so it will report events (mount, unmount) as soon as they happen. It will not detect mount points being renamed though.

Note that it only detects changes in the current mount namespace (like watching `df` would as well).

Comment: from some reason I not see the flag "-p" from the man page

Comment: @maihabunash, you need a `findmnt` from util-linux 2.20 (2011) or above.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a script like this:

```
x=""
while :; do
  df="$(awk '{print $1,$2}' /proc/mounts)" # only the first two fields are relevant
  if [ "$x" != "$df" ]; then # only diff the contents when something has changed
    diff <(echo "$df") <(echo "$x") \ # compare the two values
      --unchanged-line-format='' \
      --old-line-format='mounted: %L' \
      --new-line-format='unmounted: %L'
  fi
  x="$df"
  sleep 1 # can be increased
done
```

Depending on the information in [`/proc/mounts`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt), the script loops every 1 second and checks if something has changed. `diff` compares the old and the new value and formats the ouput.

---

When the script runs, the output would, for example, look like:

```
mounted: //srv/share /mountpoint
unmounted: /dev/sdb1 /media
```